# Python: Save progress to a log file

Tags: python, dialog

I'm running a python script that run several commands to the console.
How do I save the logs of the run to a file (for offline debug purposes)?

Is there a command in python that say "Start recording" and "Stop recording" from the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are asking is not programming related. What you want is basically log all standart streams (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`). In linux, you achieve this via `script` command:

```
script -c "script.py" debug.log
```

Comment: I want the python script to control this because I want to do some actions like - choose the log file name according to some conditions, move the log file after the python script completes to a different folder...

Comment: I was thinking of using _sys.stdout_ , _sys.stding_ and _sys.stderr_ for the file log but it only gave me what I printed to the screen in the python

It did not gave me **ALL** the plots that were printed to the screen